# Are there any good MySQL tools that "listen" to my database select queries and tells me what needs to be indexed?

Tags: mysql, database, optimization, indexing

I just built an application with many complicated SQL queries - now I want to index them. Is there a good MySQL tool that lets me know what should be indexed?

I've heard about the Slow Query Log, but is there anything else that monitors my queries and tells me what needs to be indexed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[MySQL Query Analyzer](http://www.mysql.com/products/enterprise/query.html)** helps you improve application performance by monitoring query performance and accurately pinpointing SQL code that is causing a slow down. With the new MySQL Connector Plug-ins, you can optimize performance applications more efficiently by communicating directly with the Query Analyzer.

Comment: You can check for alternative free tool. check here : http://www.xaprb.com/blog/2008/11/20/an-alternative-to-the-mysql-query-analyzer/